# Create multiple objects for an object

Tags: class

I have a `Students` class as below. My aim is to create multiple student objects and assign a couple of marks for each student. The former is done, but the latter-to assign marks for each student object- is confusing for me. As you can see, I also define a `Marks` class, but I don't know how to create multiple mark objects for each student object. Thanks for your help.

```
public class Students {
    private int ID;
    public Marks mark;
    public static int total Student=1;

    public Students(int id)
    {
        this.ID=id;
        total Student++;        
    }

    public void enter_Score(double s){
        mark =new Marks(s);
    }

    public void get_Score()
    {
        print(mark.get_Score());
    }
}

public class Marks {
    public static int total_marks;
    private double Score;

    public Marks(double score)
    {
        this.set_Score(score);
    }

    public double get_Score() {
        return Score;
    }
    public void set_Score(double score) {
        Score = score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you know how many marks a student will have, all you should have to do is create an array of Mark objects.

```
public Marks[] marks;
```

If you don't know how many marks a student will have:

```
public ArrayList<Marks>() marks;
```

Then, depending on which one you use, your method may look like:

```
public void enter_Score(double s)
{
    marks.Add(new Marks(s));
}
```

If you just use an array, you'll have to know which index you want to insert at and how big the array is. Also, remember to initialize the array or ArrayList of Marks in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if we define Marks ArrayList, we cant add a double value, right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Fixed that.